# How to flatten a list of options

Tags: filtering, option-type, reason, bucklescript

I have this piece of code now:

```rust
 results
 |> List.filter(Belt.Option.isSome)
 |> List.map(item =>
      switch (item) {
      | Some(item) => item
      }
    )
```

Can anyone make it shorter? It is a filter that removes the non-valid values followed by a map that converts/unwraps the optional values to just values.

In Scala it would just be `flatten`:

```scala
scala> List(Some("test"),None,None,Some("foo"),Some("bar"),None).flatten
res4: List[String] = List(test, foo, bar)
```

Comment: As formulated, this question is more appropriate on [codereview.se]. You should ask specific questions on SO. I'll try to just answer how to flatten a `list` of `option`s instead.

Comment: I took a surgical knife to your question to get to the meat of it. Hope that's okay. I think it's a great question formulated this way.

Comment: thanks, yes definetely better this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatten` in Scala seems to work on any kind of monad. And this kind of polymorphism, called ad-hoc polymorphism, unfortunately isn't supported in OCaml (although it's on the roadmap, asa feature called "modular implicits"). Therefore we have to write code specific for `list`s of `option`s. Using just `Belt`, we can do this:

```rust
[Some("test"), None, None, Some("foo"), Some("bar"), None]
|> Belt.List.keepMap(_, x => x)
```

`keepMap` is what is called `filterMap` in saner standard libraries, and takes a function that should return an `option` instead of a `bool` where a `None` will be filtered out and `Some(x)` will be flattened and included in the final list as just `x`.

Comment: Just a quick note that (although Glenn is not a fan) the Belt library is designed to work well with the pipe-first operator, so that could also be `[...]->Belt.List.keepMap(x => x)`.

Comment: Indeed :) The reason-specific version of the pipe-first operator is especially bad because the operator precedence is different, which can lead to surprising errors if you mix it with the ordinary pipe operator.

Comment: great, thanks. Added a variant to play with here: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=false&reason=DYUwLgBAhhC8EG0DKB7AtiAFAIjCAzmNgJQA0EAcigHYjlW3moY4BmKKJT6W2ARlABOXSjRABdANwAoUJD5xoEAD4A+CACEQwMADoAMgEtCugNYgQABwCyUS5gD65AB5x1z4jOkApfLuAoAOaYUJ4+fgHBfGFAA